# All Virtual Hosts redirect to one Host - nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress, apache2

I have two Virtual Hosts for apache & nginx. The domains are (kevin-fechner.xyz & ketogenix.de)

My own site ([kevin-fechner.xyz](https://kevin-fechner.xyz)) was working fine while I only had one domain. But after adding another one, all (only two) redirect to the new one ([ketogenix.de](https://ketogenix.de)) or reports a 502 Bad Gateway.

Both sites are running **Wordpress**.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache/2.4.29
- nginx/1.10.3
- ssl
- http2

**Curl -I:** 
*ketogenix.de*

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2018 08:39:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://ketogenix.de/
```

*kevin-fechner.xyz*

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2018 08:39:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://kevin-fechner.xyz/
```

**https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/**
- result: it's up

**Virtual Hosts**

**ketogenix.de**

*nginx*
    server {

```
    root /var/www/ketogenix.de;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ketogenix.de www.ketogenix.de;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location /wp-admin/ {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ketogenix.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ketogenix.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    if ($host = www.ketogenix.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = ketogenix.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;

    server_name ketogenix.de www.ketogenix.de;
    return 301 https://ketogenix.de$request_uri;
}
```

*apache*

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerAdmin developer.kevinfechner@gmail
        ServerName ketogenix.de
        ServerAlias www.ketogenix.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ketogenix.de

        <Directory /var/www/ketogenix.de/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**kevin-fechner.xyz**

*nginx*

```
    server {

    root /var/www/kevin-fechner.xyz;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name kevin-fechner.xyz www.kevin-fechner.xyz;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location /wp-admin/ {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2:8081$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kevin-fechner.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kevin-fechner.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = kevin-fechner.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name kevin-fechner.xyz www.kevin-fechner.xyz;
    return 301 https://kevin-fechner.xyz$request_uri;
}
```

*apache*

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:8081>
        ServerAdmin developer.kevinfechner@gmail
        ServerName kevin-fechner.xyz
        ServerAlias www.kevin-fechner.xyz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/kevin-fechner.xyz


        <Directory /var/www/kevin-fechner.xyz/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Error Logs**

tells nothing

**Things I've tried**

- adding ServerName
- changing IP adress
- changing port
- restarting nginx & apache

I hope you can help me.

Note: I've removed all my comments from the virtual host files.

Comment: Have you added `Listen 127.0.0.2:8081` to Apache config?

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot I have to edit that file as well. It's working now!

Comment: If you write that as an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't add `Listen 127.0.0.2:8081` directive to Apache configuration. That lead to 502 error, because there is no process listening on port 8081.